# Refresh visible ListView with Custom Adapter

Tags: android, listview, view, onclick, adapter

So basically the idea is that I have **2 ListViews**

**Initially:** The 2 listviews are both visible, the first one populated properly and the second one is **empty** but already shown

**After clicking a row of first ListView:** Data is fetched from Database and put properly in second one

### **Questions & Problems:**

The data are being fetched properly, but the *second ListView* remains empty and the **getView()** isn't called at all.

**1-** Is there a way to load the *second ListView* without refreshing the page?

**2-** getView() isn't called because the row isn't visible right? How can I bypass this problem?

**Tried** using **notifyDataSetChanged()** then validating the *second ListView*

#### ***Much appreciated for any assistance***

### Code

**CustomAdapter.java**

```
public class CustomAdapter extends  ArrayAdapter<ListItem>
{  
LayoutInflater inflater;
List<ListItem> items;

public CustomAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, List<ListItem> items2) {
    super(context, textViewResourceId);
    this.items = items2;
    inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}


@Override  
public int getCount() {  
    return items.size();  
}  


@Override
public ListItem getItem(int position) {
        return ((CustomAdapter) items).getItem(position);
}

@Override  
public long getItemId(int position) {  
    return position;  
}
 
@Override  
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {  
    
    final ListItem holder;
    final ListItem item = items.get(position);
    
    
    View vi=convertView;
    
    if(vi==null){
        vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.popup_toping, null);
        holder = new ListItem();
        holder.text = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.text);
        
        holder.Check = (CheckBox) vi.findViewById(R.id.check);
        
        vi.setTag(holder);
    }else{
        holder = (ListItem) vi.getTag();
   
    }
    
    
    holder.text.setText(item.t);
    
    holder.Check.setChecked(item.IsChecked);
    
    return vi;
  }

}
```

**Implementation in main activity**

```
List<ListItem> items = new ArrayList<ListItem>();;
items.add(new ListItem(){{
                            t= c.getString("first_text");
                            IsChecked = false;
                        }});
                        
                
CustomAdapter listadapter = new CustomAdapter(context, R.layout.popup, items);                      
myList.setAdapter(listadapter);
listadapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
myList.invalidate();
```

Comment: does the first ListView overlap the second one in you Layout? In that case you are just unable to see your 2nd List because there's the 1st in front of it.

Comment: From what you describe I would expect that calling notifyDataSetChanged() would have been enough.  That or changing the adapter on the second list view.  It might be easier to help you if you can post some code

Comment: I think **notifyDataSetChanged** is correct one for refreshing views. Does the second list view's layout is set correctly? How about check layout_width and layout_height values. It also be a good idea filling background color to listview and check everything is OK. If everything is fine but don't work properly, it's very helpful to show your adapter implementation for analyzing the problem.

Comment: Thanks for your reply everyone I really apperciate it.. 
I checked the layout the second one was actually overlapped by the first one and it was overlapped with a TextView.. I fixed the layout in a way that it isn't overlapped but it didn't fix my problem..
I'll show the code as soon as i'm back from work

Comment: Ok you were right I had a problem with the ListView it wasn't visible at all from the first place.. I changed the background and move it around so it's visible properly and not overlapped by any other object.. but still now luck... I've posted some code above

Comment: After trying to debug, the code can't get past myList.setAdapter(listadapter); so it must be a problem with the adapter... The adapter only gets past the constructor.. any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After long debugging and frustration, I've finally solved my problem..

**The issue:** I was setting the adapter in **doInBackground** in **AsyncTask**

**The solution:** I set the adapter in **onPostExecute** and it have solved my problem.. apparently it was interfering with the custom adapter somehow..

I'd really appreciate it if anyone can explain why though..

Thanks a lot for those who tried to help me :)

Answer (score 2):

I would advise you to look into implementing Fragments for a few reasons...

> 1. Fragments have their own lifecycle
> 2. Fragments can communicate in the same activity very easily
> 3. Best practice for supporting good UI for tablets

[image]

So if you have a ListFragment A and Fragment B you can create a listener on "ListFragment B" so that when an item is selected on ListFragment A then Fragment B is populated with your specifications. I think this will help you out a lot. Look at this example in section 10 of this article:
http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidFragments/article.html

Comment: Thanks for the reply.. Good idea, i'll check it out as soon as I get back from work

Comment: Giving the circumstances that I'm working on it would be a hard implementation.. but I +1 your post because it was helpful